# Unable to instantiate receiver after receiver package name is changed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, upgrade, classnotfoundexception

I got a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when instantiating a receiver.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.soft.OutgoingCallListener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.soft.OutgoingCallListener
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2265)
```

The log indicates Android still loads the receiver class from the old package name (com.soft.OutgoingCallListener) instead of the new one (com.new.OutgoingCallListener). I guess this situation is caused because  Android didn't unregister the old broadcast receiver when the user upgraded the apk.

Is there any workaround to avoid this error?

Comment: Make a empty old receiver class with the old package name but don't add it to the android manifest file is a workaround for this exception.

Comment: It might get resolved after restarting device but we can not programmatically in non rooted device 